# Am I allowed to embed public pictures in app / website?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I've got a question regarding use of the Instagram Api and embedding public pictures.

My app shows pictures related to a geolocation which I got with the Instagram Api at the endpoint /media.

We show under the pictures the attribution (@author, instagram logo and link to the original picture) as specified [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Are we conformed with the instagram API legal use ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based more on terms and conditions of using an API. The user should probably read the instagram API T&Cs

Comment: Hi @TommyBs, i obviously read the Instagram API T&Cs but unfortunately I didn't see any clear anwser about it. That's why i'm asking it here.

Comment: unforuntately I don't think anywhere here is going to provide any more information then what instagram provide, in theory they should be the experts. Maybe reach out to them